# VNC Viewer for Windows with NATIVE SSH tunneling support?

Tags: windows, ssh, vnc, tunnel

does somebody know of any VNC client supporting SSH tunneling natively? Of course you could use putty to setup the tunnel and then connect to to the VNC server. That's perfectly working and fine but since we're looking for a more user friendly way for non-technical customers that is no viable option.

From a linux box we can easily use tigervnc and do something like `vncviewer -via user@host localhost:<DisplayNumber> -SecurityTypes None` or use Remmina. But we weren't able to find something similar for Windows.

Does anybody have any clue whether something like that exists?

best
Andi

UPDATE 2022:

In the end we've setup a rather complex solution based on Apache guacamole (see post below). The main deal for us was guacamoles SSO capability which made it possible to connect the remote desktops with an existing LDAP instance using Keycloak as the intermediate SSO interface. Hence people can access the remote machines via the browser, the connection is secured via SSL.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't strictly client-side solution, but Gaucamole covers SSH, RDP, and VNC all in a web browser.

https://guacamole.apache.org/

Comment: thx, gonna check that out!

Comment: Is installing a guacamole server to serve a guacamole client via https which then potentially could be used by a client to connect to other servers via vnc through an ssh tunnel really the simplest solution? I find the linux solution suggested in the OP's question much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[Gosh VNC](https://github.com/zrax/gsshvnc) should work. It is 4-5 years old. It supports SSH using the libssh library and cross compiles to Windows.